# Django Reverse not found in views but URL works

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-apps

I have a project containing some **Apps** like **Account** , **Webadmin** , **etc**

Where after login i am redirecting a user to a view of **Webadmin**.
Thing is i can view that page of **Webadmin** via Browser or so! That means the link is working.

But whenever i try to redirect to view it gives me this error. Here is the traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/account/login/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar.apps.DebugToolbarConfig',
 'bootstrap3',
 'easy_pjax',
 'website',
 'account',
 'webadmin')
Installed Middleware:
('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/nihan/venv/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/nihan/workspace/hubx/account/views.py" in sign_in
  57.                     return redirect(webadmin_home)
File "/home/nihan/venv/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in redirect
  74.     return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/nihan/venv/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in resolve_url
  158.         return urlresolvers.reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File "/home/nihan/venv/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  546.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/nihan/venv/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  463.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /account/login/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'webadmin.views.list_sites' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here is my urls.py code from **Website App** ( Root app )

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns(
'',
url(r'^$', 'website.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account')),
url(r'^admin/', include('webadmin.urls', namespace='webadmin')),
url(r'^admin-panel/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

url.py code from **webadmin** App

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'create/$', 'webadmin.views.create', name='create'),
    url(r'list/$', 'webadmin.views.list_sites', name='list_sites'),
)
```

url.py code from **account** App

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url


urlpatterns = patterns( '',
    url(r'^view/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'account.views.view', name='profile'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'account.views.sign_in', name='sign_in'),
    url(r'^register/$', 'account.views.sign_up', name='sign_up'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'account.views.signout', name='logout'),
    url(r'^edit/$', 'account.views.edit', name='edit'),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<token>\d{4})/$', 'account.views.activate', name='activate'),
)
```

And i redirect to **list_sites** with this little code ( Works with other views from other apps )

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from webadmin.views import list_sites as webadmin_home

def someview(request):
    return redirect(webadmin_home)
```

Am i missing something? Why is that error orchering? How to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't redirect to a view method, you redirect to a URL. In your urls.py, you've given that URL a name, so that's what you need to use.

```
return redirect('webadmin:create')
```

Comment: I encountered this when moving from non-named patterns to namespace patterns.  Luckily my functional tests picked this up before it caused a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It'd help to see the 'account.urls' file you're referencing in websiteApp/urls.py, but it sounds like either it's not finding the "account/urls.py" file itself, or the URL conf for your "login" view within that file is incorrect.

Comment: Account url.py added in post.

Answer (score 0):

```html
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

return reverse_lazy("webadmin:list_create")
```

Comment: Welcome to the site Joris. Can you provide a bit of an explanation with your code please?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect with **"view" name**, you need **the conbination of the app name "webadmin", colon ":" and the view name "list_sites"** as shown below. In addition, you don't need to import **the view "list_sites"** as shown below:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
# from webadmin.views import list_sites as webadmin_home
            # ↑ Don't need to import ↑

def someview(request):   # Here       
    return redirect(webadmin:list_sites)
```